# What constitutes "damage" in Fortnite?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I started working on a legendary challenge in Fortnite, which requires me to "*deal damage*":

[image: Screenshot of the aforementioned legendary challenge.]

While I'm progressing rather well, I can't help but wonder what is actually counted as damage, due to the generic nature of the description. I know from my progress so far that damage dealt with weapons and the pickaxe to opposing players is counted. However, what about things like enemy structures, walls, vehicles, wildlife, etc?

After reviewing [existing questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=damage%20fortnite), visiting [the wiki](https://fortnite-archive.fandom.com/wiki/Damage_in_Battle_Royale) (could've easily missed it in the plethora of information provided there), and searching on Google, I'm not 100% certain on what, *specifically* constitutes damage in Fortnite's Battle Royale.

---

What constitutes damage with respect to this challenge?

Answer (score 2):

In order to "deal damage", you need to shoot others with a gun or hit other players with your harvesting tool. The damage needs to be inflicted to players or animals, but not structures.